# api10: connectedAndroidTest + espresso: no tests found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I want to use espresso automatically via the command line. I have written some tests which work great running from android studio and they also work with emulators api level 16 and 23. On api level 10 I get this error message (only running via `gradle connectedAndroidTest`):

```
com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.
[Nexus_4_API_10(AVD) - 2.3.7] [31mFAILED [0m
No tests found.
This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects
(e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
:app:connectedSourceDebugAndroidTest FAILED
```

(Source=flavor, Debug=build type)

i followed this guide:
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class LocaleTest{

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

@Test
public void testSomethings(){
    //some code
}
}
```

my `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile ('com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1')
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

to default config i added

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Thanks in advance, I'm running out of ideas.

EDIT(27.06.2016):
LogCat output

```
06-27 13:02:30.768 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/extensions/ActiveTestSuite$1;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.768 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/framework/Assert;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.768 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/framework/AssertionFailedError;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.768 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/framework/Protectable;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.768 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/framework/Test;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.768 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/framework/TestFailure;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.768 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/framework/TestListener;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.768 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/framework/TestResult;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.772 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/extensions/TestDecorator;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.772 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/extensions/TestSetup$1;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.777 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/framework/ComparisonFailure;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.777 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/framework/TestCase;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.777 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/framework/TestResult$1;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.777 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.784 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/extensions/ActiveTestSuite;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.784 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/extensions/RepeatedTest;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.784 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/extensions/TestSetup;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.784 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite$1;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
06-27 13:02:30.832 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/AssertionFailedError;'
06-27 13:02:30.832 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/Test;'
06-27 13:02:30.832 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/Test;'
06-27 13:02:30.836 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/extensions/ActiveTestSuite$1;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.836 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/framework/Assert;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.836 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/framework/AssertionFailedError;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.836 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/Assert;'
06-27 13:02:30.836 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/Test;'
06-27 13:02:30.836 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/framework/Protectable;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.836 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/framework/Test;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.836 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/framework/TestFailure;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.836 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/framework/TestListener;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.836 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/framework/TestResult;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.836 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite;'
06-27 13:02:30.844 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/AssertionFailedError;'
06-27 13:02:30.844 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/AssertionFailedError;'
06-27 13:02:30.844 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/AssertionFailedError;'
06-27 13:02:30.844 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/AssertionFailedError;'
06-27 13:02:30.864 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestResult;'
06-27 13:02:30.868 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestCase;'
06-27 13:02:30.868 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/Test;'
06-27 13:02:30.868 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/extensions/TestDecorator;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.868 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/extensions/TestSetup$1;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.868 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/framework/ComparisonFailure;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.868 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestResult;'
06-27 13:02:30.872 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/framework/TestCase;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.872 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/framework/TestResult$1;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.872 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.872 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite;'
06-27 13:02:30.872 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestFailure;'
06-27 13:02:30.872 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestCase;'
06-27 13:02:30.872 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestCase;'
06-27 13:02:30.888 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestCase;'
06-27 13:02:30.888 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite;'
06-27 13:02:30.888 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/Protectable;'
06-27 13:02:30.888 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite;'
06-27 13:02:30.888 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite;'
06-27 13:02:30.888 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite;'
06-27 13:02:30.888 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/extensions/ActiveTestSuite;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.888 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/extensions/RepeatedTest;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.888 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/extensions/TestSetup;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.888 4485-4485/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not verifying 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite$1;': multiple definitions
06-27 13:02:30.888 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestResult;'
06-27 13:02:30.888 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite;'
06-27 13:02:30.896 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite;'
06-27 13:02:30.896 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/Test;'
06-27 13:02:30.904 4485-4485/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite;'
```